# python: select a sublist with a list length limit

Tags: python

> players = [ a long list of (id, float) tuples with each id unique,
>   order by highest float]
>
> on_teams = [ a list of unique ids, every on_teams id is also in the
>   players list]

```
picked = set(on_teams)
best_remaining = []
for best_player in players:
    if best_player[0] not in picked:
        best_remaining.append(best_player)
    if len(best_remaining) == 5: break
```

When I use six lines of code to do a simple thing, such as "get the five best remaining players", I wonder if there isn't a more elegant, pythonic solution. It's a simple problem, no doubt, but is there a better way to code it?

UPDATE:
My code run 100,000 times, runs in 0.24 secs. When I run:

```
best_remaining = [(id, float) for id, float in players if id not in picked][:5]
```

The code runs in 4.61 secs (100,000x). So the code looks and scans nicer, but it create the whole list then slices it. So now my question is a little different. With speed as a constraint, is there a better way to code up the search for the '5 best remaining players`?

UPDATE:

```
best_remaining = list(islice((p for p in players if p[0] not in picked), 5))
```

This code runs trivially longer than my code. To me at least, it has the value of a list comprehension. And best of all, it shows me a good place to work on my code habits. Thanks

Comment: Err, are you not just after `players[:5]` ?

Comment: No, because I need to know that none of `players[:5]` is in `on_teams`

Comment: So, `picked = set(on_teams)`, `[(id, fl) for id, fl in players if id not in picked][:5]` (or, ideally, use `islice()` and a generator expression for optimal performance).

Comment: It might be a simple problem, but you're not explaining it simply.  Can you try to tell us in words what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks. Just want I wanted to learn. Pls write it up as an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generator, and then `islice` it to a max of 5 results...

```
from itertools import islice
picked = set(on_teams)
players = list(islice((p for p in players if p[0] not in picked), 5))
```

Comment: You forgot the actual `islice`.

Comment: To explain why this is better than a simple list comprehension - it is lazy, so only pulls the values it *needs* to do this (the first five that are not picked), rather than calculating them all just to (potentially) throw many away.

Comment: if picked is large this can be very slow ... (probably larger than can be realistically expected for this problem)

Comment: @JoranBeasley not sure I'm following - could you explain?

Comment: @JonClements ... nevermind I have proven my self wrong ... looks like this is faster than my numpy solution ... but I swear I have had huge slow downs using this technique, and had to move to numpy for speed gains

Answer (score 0):

numpy is great for something like this

```
players = numpy.array([[1,1.1],[2,1.2],[3,3.2],[4,4.4]])
on_teams = [1,3]
print players[~numpy.in1d(players[:,0],on_teams)]  #all players not on teams (in example 2,4)
# now you can just select the top n players
```